# use variable inside json file with Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json, variables

Didn't find anything on this.
The question is:
Is it possible to add variable to json file and then use it in following way

json file:

```
{
  "s1": {
   "text": "Benefit from falling {{ symbol }} prices as well as rising {{ symbol }} prices. Buy or sell instantly"
  }
}
```

Contoller:

```
 $scope.symbol = 'gold';
```

View:

```
 <p>{{content.s1.title}}</>
```

What I want to get is:

Benefit from falling gold prices as well as rising gold prices. Buy or sell instantly

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3):

You should use [`$interpolate`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate) for that:

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div>
      {{resolveText(content.s1.text)}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('app', []).
controller('ctrl', function($scope, $interpolate) {
  $scope.content = {
    "s1": {
      "text": "Benefit from falling {{ symbol }} prices as well as rising {{ symbol }} prices. Buy or sell instantly"
    }
  };

  $scope.symbol = 'this is a test';

  $scope.resolveText = function(t) {
    return $interpolate(t)($scope);
  };
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/c3011evh/).

P.S. the `resolveText` is a quick way to show you how this works. I think it's better to create a directive that will encapsulate the logic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.prototype.replace`

Example assuming `mystr` is your JSON content.

```
$scope.symbol = 'gold';
mystr.replace('<symbol>', $scope.symbol);
```

returns

```
{
  "s1": {
    "text": "Benefit from falling gold prices as well as rising gold prices. Buy or sell instantly"
  }
}
```

Usage : `string.replace(substr|regex, newSubstr|function)`

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String/replace)

Comment: Right, that what I was thinking about. But the first way is exactly what I was after. Thanks anyway

Comment: No problem.
Don't forgot to valid the answer if it has solved your problem.
And a simple vote for other answers can be a good alternative to say "Good job but can do better".

Comment: @chalasr - This is NOT a good way to solve this problem. Do you want to use angularjs or build your own custom framework? Plus, this wont work if the $scope.symbol will change it's value (or do you want to add a watch and run your code?)

Comment: It's just a quick way using pure javascript. I know your answer is better because it uses angularjs built-in methods. But what I'm proposing reproduces the same work as your answer, where `$scope.resolveText` is your watcher and `$interpolate` your substring replacer.
It's just the `angularjs` way, and thank's for it.

Answer (score 0):

Use [$interpolate service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate):

```
var result = $interpolate("Some string with {{var}}")({var: "Value"});
```

[Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Pb77rkVU8NsKOtGwS1nM?p=preview)